# In my render layer, all my collections are damaged by the last one. python programming in maya

Tags: overriding, render, layer

I  work in Python. I want to create a render layers with different collections each of them having a shader override. But each time a new override comes, it overwrites the others. Someone can tell me where I'm wrong ?

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from maya.app import renderSetup
import maya.api.OpenMaya as OpenMaya
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.override as override
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.selector as selector
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.collection as collection
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.renderLayer as renderLayer
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.renderSetup as renderSetup

rs = renderSetup.instance()   
try: rLyr = rs.getRenderLyyer("colourLayer")
except: rLyr = rs.createRenderLayer("colourLayer")

listRED=('pCo*1')
listGREEN=('pTo*1')
listBLUE=('pCu*1')
listNOIR=('pCy*1')
listWHITE=('pSp*1')

mel.eval('polyCone -r 1 -h 2 -sx 20 -sy 1 -sz 0 -ax 0 1 0 -rcp 0 -cuv 3 -ch 1;polyCube -w 1 -h 1 -d 1 -sx 1 -sy 1 -sz 1 -ax 0 1 0 -cuv 4 -ch 1;polyTorus -r 1 -sr 0.5 -tw 0 -sx 20 -sy 20 -ax 0 1 0 -cuv 1 -ch 1;move -r -os -wd 3.246282 0 2.41639 ;select -r pCone1 ;move -r -os -wd -1.846807 0 2.730534 ;polyCylinder -r 1 -h 2 -sx 20 -sy 1 -sz 1 -ax 0 1 0 -rcp 0 -cuv 3 -ch 1;move -r -os -wd -4.264135 0 -2.713963 ;polySphere -r 1 -sx 20 -sy 20 -ax 0 1 0 -cuv 2 -ch 1;move -r -os -wd 1.622641 0 -3.675104 ;')

rdm = cmds.shadingNode ('lambert', asShader=True, n='redMat_shd') #red material
[cmds.setAttr( '{}.{}'.format(rdm, channel), 1, 0, 0, type='double3') for channel in ('color','incandescence')]
redColl = rLyr.createCollection('redCollection')
over_red = redColl.createOverride('redOverride', OpenMaya.MTypeId(0x58000386))
redColl.getSelector().setPattern(listRED)
over_red.setShader(str(rdm))

gdm = cmds.shadingNode ('lambert', asShader=True, n='greenMat_shd') #green material
[cmds.setAttr( '{}.{}'.format(gdm, channel), 0, 1, 0, type='double3') for channel in ('color','incandescence')]
greenColl = rLyr.createCollection('greenCollection')
over_green = greenColl.createOverride('greenOverride', OpenMaya.MTypeId(0x58000386))
greenColl.getSelector().setPattern(listGREEN)
over_green.setShader(str(gdm))

bdm = cmds.shadingNode ('lambert', asShader=True, n='blueMat_shd') #blue material
[cmds.setAttr( '{}.{}'.format(bdm, channel), 0, 0, 1, type='double3') for channel in ('color','incandescence')]
blueColl = rLyr.createCollection('blueCollection')
over_blue = blueColl.createOverride('blueOverride', OpenMaya.MTypeId(0x58000386))
blueColl.getSelector().setPattern(listBLUE)
over_blue.setShader(str(bdm))
```

by advance thank you

Answer (score 0):

finally I was use the bad override method.

```
import maya.app.renderSetup.model.renderSetup as renderSetup

listRED = ('list of objects you want to reassign')
rsg = 'the_shading_engine_which_ll_be_connected_to_those_objects'

rs = renderSetup.instance()
rLyr = rs.getRenderLyyer("colourLayer") #the new render layer
redColl = rLyr.createCollection('redCollection') #the collection
redColl.getSelector().setPattern(listRED) #the selection of objects
over_red = redColl.createOverride("redOverride", "materialOverride") #the override
over_red.setMaterial(rsg) # the reassignation of material
```